# Python- Robot Framework Rebot Using List

Tags: python, robotframework

I am attempting to use a list of output files to merge them into one single file. I need to use a list to store these different files but when I call the rebot function using the list I get the following error,

```
[ ERROR ] Reading XML source '<in-memory file>' failed: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I have tried converting the list to a string value but that will read the list as one long string, which is not what I want. Does anyone know how I can use a list and the rebot function? Here is my example code:

```
import robot
list_1 = ["output1.xml", "output2.xml"]
robot.rebot(list_1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a simple solution by using `robot.rebot_cli()` instead of `robot.rebot()`. The answer to my example code shown above is as follows. Also, (a side note) running `rebot_cli` will terminate the program once it is finished merging the files together. To prevent this from happening I included `exit=False` :

```
import robot
list_1 = ["output1.xml", "output2.xml"]
robot.rebot_cli(list_1,exit=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Robot Framework API guide for Rebot](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.4/autodoc/robot.html#module-robot.rebot) the following example is given for this particular question:

```
from robot import rebot

with open('stdout.txt', 'w') as stdout:
    rebot('o1.xml', 'o2.xml', name='Example', log=None, stdout=stdout)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this helps. You are still listing the different .xml files out one by one. I need a way to call them from a list, rather than just typing them in individually.

Comment: The rebot command takes them as two arguments. If you want to wrap with another function that takes a 2-item list and splits it into the rebot argument 1 and 2, shouldn't be too difficult.